# Chaining/Grouping Celery Tasks in separate docker containers

Tags: python, docker, celery, celery-task, chain

I've been using celery for a couple of months and, stumbled upon a case where i just don't see any info or even an example of what i intend to achieve.

In this specific case i have a docker container running an API and two other separate containers with celery workers.

I have my queues and tasks defined and i call a task with the send_task method. Example:

> r = celery_app.send_task('task_a')

Similarly i have another container with "task_b" that can be called the same way as "task_a".

I'm defining my tasks by updating the configuration of my celery app and detailing their respective queues since they run on other separate containers.

ex:

```
celery_app.conf.update({
    'broker_url': 'amqp://admin:mypass@rabbit:5672',
    'result_backend': 'redis://redis:6379/0',
    'imports': (
        'tasks_a_dev',
        'tasks_b_dev',
    ),
    'task_routes': {
        'task_a': {'queue': 'qtasks_a_dev'},
        'task_b': {'queue': 'qtasks_b_dev'},
    },
    'task_serializer': 'json',
    'result_serializer': 'json',
    'accept_content': ['json']
})
```

Is there anyway i can chain these two tasks together while passing the result of task_a to task_b?

Answer (score 0):

If you use Celery > v3.0.0, you can use [chaining](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/userguide/canvas.html#chains).

So if you wanted task_b to run with the result of task_a, you could do the following.

```py
from celery import chain

@task()
def task_a(a, b):
    time.sleep(5)
    return a + b

@task()
def task_b(a, b):
    time.sleep(5)
    return a + b

# the result of the first job will be the first argument of the second job
res = chain(task_a.s(1, 2), task_b.s(3)).apply_async()

# Alternatively, you could do the following

res_2 = (task_a.s(1, 2) | task_b.s(3)).apply_async()

# check ret status to get result
if ret.status == u'SUCCESS':
    print "result:", ret.get()
```

Comment: This is what the documentation stated indeed, although i'm not quite sure how to diverge from using the method `send_task` and using signature instead, could you provide me an example of how to assign a task to a signature?

Comment: How are you defining your tasks? I've modified my answer to include task definition as well.

Comment: I updated my question to exemplify how i'm defining my tasks, your solution makes total sense if the tasks are definined under the same file you make your request, but i have them currently defined in different containers they link with said containers by the name of the task and the declarated queue.